# How to take JMC output into a file?

Tags: java, windows, jmc

I want to log the output of Java mission control console in a file (txt or xml) so that I can get the file for putting it into Splunk.
.

Referring to https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-5/jmc-user-guide/logging.htm#JMCCI129 I tried to made the changes, but it did not work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.